# Can xsd type of 'anyURI' contain spaces?

Tags: xml, xsd, saml-2.0

Is it valid for an XML element of type **anyURI** to contain spaces?

The schema says it is, but says its highly discouraged.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#anyURI

```
NOTE: Spaces are, in principle, allowed in the ·lexical space· of anyURI, however, their use is highly discouraged (unless they are encoded by %20).
```

A third party is setting this Audience with non escaped spaces, e.g. "Website One". But this seems very strange, can someone confirm I'm not going mad please :)

**Update**

I should have mentioned I'm referring to the Audience element in the SAML2 Assertion schema, which just states it as **anyUri**, but if it can equally be a string ("one two three") why is it even set as anyUri.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First point: the whiteSpace facet of the xs:anyURI data type is defined as "collapse", which means that leading and trailing whitespace characters are ignored, and internal sequences of whitespace are equivalent to a single space character.

Second point: as stated by @forty-two, if you can get a legal URI by applying percent-encoding, then it's a legal (XSD 1.0) instance of `xs:anyURI`: specifically, `"website one"` is a legal representation of the relative URI `"website%20one"`.

(I like to use the term "wannabe URI" to describe a string that isn't a URI, but becomes a URI after you apply escaping. XSD 1.0 allows wannabe URIs. One of the key difficulties here is that you don't know whether the URI is already escaped; if you apply escaping twice you get `"website%2520one"` which gets you into a mess.)

Finally, in XSD 1.1 all bets are off: "The value space of anyURI is the set of finite-length sequences of zero or more characters (as defined in [XML]) that ·match· the Char production from [XML].". Essentially, there had been so many debates about exactly what was legal and what wasn't, given the variety of URI/IRI/LEIRI specs, that the schema group decided that as far as validity is concerned, anything goes.

Comment: I don't think it's true that you get double escaping if you follow the [encoding process defined by the XLink specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xlink-20010627/#link-locators) as it explicitly excludes `%` from the list of characters that get escaped.  The process turns a wannabe URI (nice term) into a URI, but is a no-op when applied to an actual URI.

Answer (score 3):

Not a firm confirmation, but you're probably not going mad, at least not for this reason.

Even though spaces are allowed in **anyURI**, it would be very silly to include them since they are not allowed in a URI reference according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

However, in the XML schema specification, just before the note you cited, there is also this passage:

> The ·lexical space· of anyURI is finite-length character sequences which, when the algorithm defined in Section 5.4 of [XML Linking Language] is applied to them, result in strings which are legal URIs according to [RFC 2396], as amended by [RFC 2732].

The referred algorithm specifies that before resolving a URI reference derived from an anyURI element, you should escape "illegal" characters.

Answer (score 2):

RFC 2396 (which predates 3986, and was current at the time XML Schema was produced) talks of using whitespace characters "to delimit URI in many contexts".

As such we could assume that the strings `"http://example.net/"` and `"   http://example.net/   "` were both representations of the same URI. That is, they occupy the same point in *value space* in XML Schema terms, but differ in terms of *lexical space*.

This is also likely to cause headaches, so you're better off just not using spaces at all.

Comment: Good point. The third party are generating this element as a sentence with spaces ("Website One"), so I don't have any control over it, but wanted to be able to say "this is wrong", but unfortunately it appears valid, even if far from desirable.

Comment: It's a valid way of doing something that at the next level is invalid though; the URI itself should not contain a space.

Comment: My c# code threw an error when I passed it to the Uri() class but when I parsed it as a relative URL it seemed to accept it.

Comment: That's interesting. If you can though, just complain about the invalid URI; it doesn't matter that the XML is valid in XMLSchema terms if the data itself isn't.